# NSMutable array sort 10 after 1

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting

I have an array with playlists with numbers I like to sort, everything is good until my number reaches 10. The array sort 10 after 1 instead of 9, how can I fix that?

Here is my code :

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:playlists];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
playlists = (NSMutableArray*)[sortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
playlists = [meshGroups mutableCopy];
```

**EDIT:**

Here what I changed so that the array sort 10 after 9 and not after 1:

I changed

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
```

to

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [(NSString*) obj1 compare:(NSString*) obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two obvious issues, only one is sorting.

First, your `10` is coming in the wrong place as your `NSSortDescriptor` is doing *lexicographic* ("alphabetical" but extended over all characters) sorting and a string starting with a `1` comes before one starting with a `2` etc.

To address this you need to do a comparison which sorts numbers in the string by their numeric value. `NSString`'s `compare:options:` method with the `NSNumericSearch` option specified will do this.

Use one of the `NSArray` or `NSSortDescriptor` methods which takes a *comparator*, i.e. a block, argument and call `compare:options:` in the block. Consult the documentation for `NSString`, `NSArray`, `NSSortDescriptor` etc. for the details.

Second you write:

> ```
> playlists = (NSMutableArray*)[sortedArray...
> ```

You **cannot** simply cast an `NSArray` to an `NSMutableArray` to make it mutable. Use `mutableCopy` to do this, as you do in your next line:

> ```
> playlists = [meshGroups mutableCopy];
> ```

which promptly discards the sorted array you just produced...

HTH

Comment: Thanks, has been really informative. I will do the changes

Answer (score -2):

You can use the

`- (NSArray<ObjectType> *)sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr`

API and write your *own comparing logic* in ***cmptr block***.

This is the easiest and most reliable way I know to achieve the output you desire. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: I was about to this now, thought I could be a better way

Comment: You can try sortedArrayUsingSelector, although I prefer blocks so I answered the one with blocks. Do accept the answer if it solves the problem to help anyone seeking the anwer in future.

Comment: Why the downvote, who ever did it. Does my answer not help the case?